# Password request redirect to another page

Tags: 7, rules, users

I click on forgot password page

it redirect me to **http://example.com/user/password** which is fine

now when i enter email id . it redirect me to

**"http//example.com/user */**. I want it to redirect another page

**http://example.com/request-access**

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: you can use `rules` module to accomplish this.

Comment: Can u tell me what rule i need to implement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your own submit handler to the form :

```
function CUSTOM_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'user_reset') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'CUSTOM_form_submit';
  }
}

function CUSTOM_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'request-access';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is within the feature set of the [LoginToboggan module](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), but you may want to give it a try since at least similar features are on the featre list:

> 7. Optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail address.

and also plays together with [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules):

> 12. Integrates with Rules module to do various tasks when a user validates via email validation process (see http://drupal.org/node/880904 for an example)

Answer (score 0):

I think **Login Destination** module will be helpfull. Just try it.
 Check https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, I prefer to have a custom trigger which will give freedom to end user to select the page of his choice whenever he/she wants, instead of fiddling with code every time. Use below code to create a custom module and install it in your environment. Once done you will find the trigger in your triggers list.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_trigger_info().
 * 
 * Below we have created one trigger for passoword reset which will help user to define an action for it based on the req.
 * 
 * The trigger belongs to User group and has a custom created hook called user_password_reset
 * 
 * This will appear in the list of triggers
 */

function your_module_trigger_info() {
    return array(
            'user' => array(
                    'user_password_reset' => array(
                            'label' => t('After password reset'),
                    ),
            ),
    );
}

/**
 * 
 * @param  $form Form data
 * @param  $form_state 
 * @param  $form_id
 * 
 * Implemtents hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
 * 
 * This is used to call our trigger event on password reset request form submit
 */

function your_module_form_user_pass_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'your_module_user_password_reset';
}

/**
 *  Custom function your_module_user_password_reset()
 *  
 *  This will execute actions assigned to the trigger.
 */

function your_module_user_password_reset() {
    $aids = trigger_get_assigned_actions('user_password_reset');

    $context = array(
            'group' => 'user',
            'hook' => 'user_password_reset',
    );

    actions_do(array_keys($aids), (object) $options, $context);
}
```

Please let me know if you find any issues with it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to close all the sessions after reset password, you can play with Rules and hybridauth modules.

Steps:

1. Install the module and configure it.
2. Add a rule "Logout after password update" or whatever name you want to give here.
3. Select event "After updating an existing user account" .
4. Once you select an event you will have to add conditions and actions based on which your rule works. Add a condition "Execute php code".
5. Now a page will get opened where you can add your one liner php code.

   return $account_unchanged->pass != $account->pass;

save it and go back to your rules page.

6. Add an action "Destroy session" and you are done.

Comment: And how can he configure the target URL now?

Comment: Once you are done with the reset password , you will be taken to login page so no need to configure target URL.